# How to update multiple tables in Spring CassandraRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Suppose I have a users table in cassandra called 'UserPrincipal', the repository will look something like the following

```
public interface UserRepository extends CassandraRepository<UserPrincipal> 
{
   @Query("SELECT * FROM UserPrincipal WHERE email = ?0")
   UserPrincipal findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);   
}
```

If I need to query the table with username for example, I have to denormalize the table and create a duplicate and let's call it UserPrincipalByUsername which is identical to the first one and only different with the primary key, now, can I use the following Interface as a repository? and what about saving/removing a user to/from  both tables simultaneously to maintain data consistency?

```
public interface UserRepository extends CassandraRepository<UserPrincipal> 
{
   @Query("SELECT * FROM UserPrincipal WHERE email = ?0")
   UserPrincipal findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);   

   @Query("SELECT * FROM UserPrincipalByUsername WHERE username= ?0")
   UserPrincipal findByUsername(String username);   
}
```

It can be noted that two separate interfaces can be used to deal with each table alone, but still, I need to have some logic to maintain the consistency at some point.

I am using Cassandra 2.0.11, CQL spec 3.1.1, Spring data Cassandra 1.3.2 and Spring boot 1.3.1

Comment: `UserPrincipal` and `UserPrincipalByUsername` are different tables? with different primary key? you can create secondary index on `UserPrincipal` to query using name instead of de-normalizing it ?

Comment: In practice you can not use cassandra index for high cardinality column, which is the case for the username.

Comment: Using `@Query` will suit your needs. Keeping both tables in sync is your job. You _could_ use atomic batch operations but those are quite expensive as they keep your Cassandra nodes busy. How about some batch job that runs out of band and keeps track of cleanups/adding missing data?

Comment: Hi @Hasson, Could you please let us know how you solved this?

Comment: @Baga please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only procedure I found to solve this is, as mentioned in the question, to use two separate interfaces to deal with each table alone, I have added a wrapper class to use both of them to `save` using one call, but this dosen't guarantee consistency all the time (in a case of server/system failure for example), but this is ok in my specific application.